# Como corrigir Panel piscando (Flickering control) quando desenha algo?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Fiz um exemplo quando acontece esse `pisca-pisca`, é só colocar o controle `Panel` no formulário e executar.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
        this.KeyPress += Form1_KeyPress;
        this.panel1.Paint += panel1_Paint;
        rectangle = new Rectangle()
        {
            Width = 20,
            Height = 20,
        };
    }

    Rectangle rectangle;
    Keys keys;

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        keys = e.KeyCode;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.Invalidate();
        switch (keys)
        {
            case Keys.D:
                {
                    rectangle.X += 10;
                }
                break;
            case Keys.A:
                {
                    rectangle.X -= 10;
                }
                break;
            case Keys.W:
                {
                    rectangle.Y -= 10;
                }
                break;
            case Keys.S:
                {
                    rectangle.Y += 10;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), rectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 10), this.panel1.ClientRectangle);
    }
```

Dá para perceber que ao pressionar uma das `Keys` acima, a borda do `Panel` e inclusive o próprio `retângulo` pisca simultaneamente.
Quando acontecia isso no `Form`, eu dava o seguinte comando:

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Aí parava de piscar, mas no panel não tem isso. O que fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é um problema antigo de aplicações Windows Forms, o que acontece é que o processamento grafico da tela não consegue carregar corretamente a atualização da tela, porque a ação tomada é mais rápida que o próprio carregamento da tela.

Existe uma série de artigos da Microsoft e soluções que prometem resolver o problema, mais cada caso é um caso, pois depende muito da quantidade de gráficos que voce tem no seu formulário e também da quantidade de memória virtual disponível para o processamento gráfico do seu computador.

Abaixo um compilado de links e uma soluções que resolve 80% dos casos onde o Flickering (pisca-pisca) acontece.

Links importantes:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/15d8a45c-f2c3-49a6-9312-11ead7b05662/how-to-remove-flickering-from-windows-form-in-c?forum=winforms

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046560/how-to-stop-flickering-c-sharp-winforms

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls

Minha solução:

- Configure o seu formulário com a opção DoubleBuffered;
- Coloque o código abaixo no dentro do construtor do seu formulário:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

- Inclua esse trecho de código no seu formulário:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams handleParam = base.CreateParams;
        handleParam.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
        return handleParam
     }
}
```

Sendo assim o seu código ficaria assim:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
        this.KeyPress += Form1_KeyPress;
        this.panel1.Paint += panel1_Paint;
        rectangle = new Rectangle()
        {
            Width = 20,
            Height = 20,
        };

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams handleParam = base.CreateParams;
            handleParam.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;     
            return handleParam;
        }
    }

    Rectangle rectangle;
    Keys keys;

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        keys = e.KeyCode;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.Invalidate();
        switch (keys)
        {
            case Keys.D:
                rectangle.X += 10;
                break;
            case Keys.A:
                rectangle.X -= 10;
                break;
            case Keys.W:
                rectangle.Y -= 10;
                break;
            case Keys.S:
                rectangle.Y += 10;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), rectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 10), this.panel1.ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Posso fazer isso com qualquer controle?

Comment: Sim, pois o problema não é o controle em si e sim o carregamento do formulário

Comment: Lembrando que esse código não é bala de prata, depende muito da quantidade de controles no formulário e o que cada controle carrega, mais resolve na maioria das vezes.